# Verifying ERC20 Contract that uses OpenZeppelin's library contracts

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, erc-20

I deployed an `ERC-20` Token contract and would like to now verify it on `etherscan.io`

My contract utilizes Open-Zeppelin's library of contracts - which means it's importing one of *their* contracts into itself, like so:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";


contract MyTestCoin is ERC20 {

   // etc.
```

Of course, it so happens that this imported `ERC20.sol` contract imports *other* contracts into *itself* as well, so the rabbit hole gets even deeper.

So my question is basically this: if I want to verify *my* contract, can I just verify IT, or do I need to also somehow verify every other contract it imports as well?

Also, what `Open Source License Type` should I choose when I go through the verification process? `etherscan.io` has like 9 different options you can choose from - and I can't tell what's right for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

ok, I tried using `truffle flattened` in Terminal. It combined and outputted the code of all the files I pointed it to into one stream, so I copy-pasted that code into the etherscan verification page and got this error:

```
Compiler debug log:
 Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI
 Found the following ContractName(s) in source code : ERC20, IERC20, MyTestCoin, SafeMath
 But we were unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2)
 For troubleshooting, you can try compiling your source code with the Remix - Solidity IDE and check for exceptions
```

So - what's that all about?

---

**UPDATE # 2**

As per the suggestion in the error message I received, I took all the code and compiled it in `Remix` - there were no errors. So the code seems to be just fine...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have basically three options.

**1. Truffle-flattener**

You can use [truffle-flattener](https://github.com/nomiclabs/truffle-flattener) to create a file that contains all the imported contract's source codes. The result can be used to easily verify a contract on Etherscan.

**2. truffle-plugin-verify**

You may also try [truffle-plugin-verify](https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-plugin-verify) if you are using Truffle. You'll need an [API key from Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/apis) for this.

**3. Etherscan with multiple files**

Or you can choose Etherscan verification with multiple files and add every single file individually. (not recommended)

> Also, what Open Source License Type should I choose when I go through the verification process? etherscan.io has like 9 different options you can choose from - and I can't tell what's right for this.

If you don't know yet, choose 'None', if you don't really care pick 'Unlicensed' or 'MIT'. If you want something specific, look up each license's definition.

Comment: ok, I tried option 1 - and got an error. Please see my updated question for the specifics. (And thanks!)

Comment: @Sirab33 Please open up new separate questions for that.

Comment: Just got it working. Needed to select "YES" in the "OPTIMIZATION" drop menu choice when doing the verification. Will mark yours as the right answer :-)